# Split a List of String Arrays into a Custom Model in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I seem to have gotten myself into a bind. I got data from a website and split it into text files, each text file containing say a Name, email and phone.

I have managed to read in all the text files into a List. Each String[] array contains the name, email and phone. I can identify the original page number from the List index.

Now I am trying to create a Person and then have a list of people. The Person class is

```
public class Person {
    private int pageNum;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String cell;
}
```

This block of code does the relevant adding to lists

```
private List<String[]> peopleRaw = new ArrayList<String[]>();
List<People> people = new ArrayList<People>();

/*
 * read in the people from all the files and store each persons details
 * in an array. then add each array to a list of arrays
 */
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
    String fileName = "people/" + i + ".txt";
    String[] _lines = Utils.getLinesFromFile(getBaseContext(), fileName);

    peopleRaw.add(_lines);
}

for (int j = 0; j < peopleRaw.size(); j++) {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int k = 0; k < peopleRaw.get(j).length; k++) {
        lines.add(peopleRaw.get(j)[k]);
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < lines.size(); l += 3) {
        String _nm = lines.get(l);
        String _email = lines.get(l + 1);
        String _cell = lines.get(l + 2);
        Person _prsn = new Person(j, _nm, _email, _cell);

        people.add(_prsn);

        lines.clear();
    }
}
```

I am getting an index out of bounds on String _email = lines.get(l + 1);

I have thought of going the sql way and creating a tiny database but I think it will simply bring back the problem. Having to split the files into a Custom Model.

I have to admit I am a bit way over my head and I am now confused with my own project. Someone please help.

Comment: You have `for (int l = 0; l < lines.size(); l += 3) ` so at some point `l` will be on the last line, but you try to do something with ` lines.get(l + 1);` and ` lines.get(l + 2);` which I would guess is causing the error you see. Make the loop stop sooner?

Comment: maybe change the for-loop condition to something like this: `l < lines.size()`

Comment: What is `List<People>`, don't you mean `List<Person>`???

Comment: Pretty sure, you'll have to share your parsing method `Utils.getLinesFromFile()` because we don't know what your file looks like.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl, the getLinesFromFile() method works correctly. I am able to open all 96 files and parse the data into a List<String[]>. The problem is iterating through the List<String[]> and for each String[], taking element 0, 1 and 2 then moving to 3, 4 and 5 if they exist etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your Person class smarter, by adding the parsing method inside of it. Now, the only one who knows how to create a `Person` is itself. Although, you could move this to a utility class, to make it cleaner looking and less polluted.

All you need to do is read in the text file, and feed the lines into the parsing method to create your `Person` objects.

```
import java.text.ParseException;

public class Person {
    private int pageNum;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String cell;

    public int getPageNum() {
        return pageNum;
    }

    public void setPageNum(int pageNum) {
        this.pageNum = pageNum;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCell() {
        return cell;
    }

    public void setCell(String cell) {
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    public Person() {
        this(0, "", "", "");
    }

    public Person(int pageNum, String name, String email, String cell) {
        this.pageNum = pageNum;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Person [pageNum=%s, name=%s, email=%s, cell=%s]", pageNum, name, email, cell);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "1,John Doe,john@doe.org,555-555-5555";

        try {
            Person johnDoe = Person.parse(data, ",");
            System.out.println(johnDoe);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Person parse(String input, String delimiter) throws ParseException {
        Person result = new Person();
        String[] tokens = input.split(delimiter);

        if (tokens.length != 4) {
            throw new ParseException(String.format("Malformed Person input: %s%n", input), 0);
        }

        result.setPageNum(Integer.parseInt(tokens[0], 10));
        result.setName(tokens[1]);
        result.setEmail(tokens[2]);
        result.setCell(tokens[3]);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the structure of this class. I am definitely going to use parts of the code, but it doesn't seem to address my question. The data I have is a List of String Arrays and I am having a challenge selecting each 3 Array elements and creating a Person from each

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to refactor your code a bit so that you yourself understand what you've written:

Never use a local variable `l` because it is unclear to me what `l + 1` is..

As about the problem - it could be due to the fact that you probably have 4 lines and not a `mod 3` as you expect...

Something is broken in the incoming data

Comment: I will get rid of the int l variable. i am pretty sure I need to have an Loop within a Loop for this. I have done similar in C#, iterating over a Collection of Collections but java's foreach loop gives me a headache on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it. I don't know if this is hacky or the best way to go about it:

```
List<String[]> peopleRaw = new ArrayList<String[]>();

List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_PAGES; i++) {
        String fileName = "people/" + i + ".txt";

        String[] _lines = Utils.getLinesFromFile(getBaseContext(), fileName);

        peopleRaw.add(_lines);

    }

    for (int j = 0; j < peopleRaw.size(); j++) {

        for (int k = 0; k + 2 < peopleRaw.get(j).length; k += 3) {
            Person prsn = new Person(j, peopleRaw.get(j)[k], peopleRaw.get(j)[k + 1],
                    peopleRaw.get(j)[k + 2]);

            people.add(prod);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("People", people.get(i).toString());
    }
```

I guess I can free up some memory by emptying the peopleRaw List or the GC does that for me but it's working now.